# Android attribute "xxxx" has already been defined

Tags: android

I don't know if anyone know this library or have used it ( https://github.com/johnkil/Print ) but the main ideea is to make `icons` from different `fonts`.

I need it because I need to implement a library that use it ( https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView ).

I get all type of error like: `Error:(2) Attribute "iconSize" has already been defined` matching other files from other `libraries` already imported.

Does anyone know how can I solve this ? Is there a way how to make the compiler ignore this ?

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile('org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.httpclient:2.1.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.restlet', module: 'jse'
        exclude group: 'org.restlet.ext', module: 'ss1'
    }
    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            exclude 'META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.ClientHelper'
        }
    }
    compile 'net.koofr:java-koofr:1.2.8'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
    compile 'org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.jackson:2.1.2'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.0.1'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:3.1.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.wnafee:vector-compat:1.0.5'
    compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'
    //    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.0.5@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.victor:lib:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: does your project use gradle build?

Comment: yes, and I think I figured out what is the problem after searching more about this, seems that print library use some attrs that are already defined in other libraries https://github.com/johnkil/Print/blob/master/print/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml

Comment: I have also tried to download the project and import it as a module to project, modify the attrs and use it, but I get error because he use some notations on gradle instead of values.

Comment: *because he use some notations on gradle instead of values*...sorry, hardly understand what you're saying.